# Dying Peace Lily

Tags: diagnosis

I have a Peace Lily which has done well very a year in front of sliding doors. It has started drooping like it needed water to which I watered it and usually it perks right back up. It didn't this time and I thought maybe it got too cold in front of the sliding doors so I was going to move it. I took it out of the basket it was in and there was water standing. Maybe that was the reason..... There were roots growing along the side of the pot and dirty dirt so I cleaned all that off along with the roots and moved it to a warmer area with indirect light and it did worse. Did I kill it completely and is there ay coming back from this? I have trimmed all the dead leaves off of it and when I watered it the other day, the water which dripped out of it was very dark reddish brown. Does this mean anything? Help me if possible. 
Kim

Comment: A photograph of both plant and the pot would be helpful, but when you found these roots, did you just break them off, or turn the plant out of its pot to see if it needs a bigger one?